# fixed sidebar is not working in glass website in bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, sidebar, bootstrap-5

**Hello Dear Respected Developers**
I'm New in web development and I'm practicing but while practicing I'm sometimes fighting with my CSS so Today I've a question for you
I want to make a **fixed sidebar** but I can't I tried a lot and google a lot but my problem is very unknown maybe so that's why I'm asking here
this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mySidebtn').click(()=>{
        $('.sidebg').toggleClass('hideSidebar')
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('hideSidebar')
    })
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: #43C6AC;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F8FFAE, #43C6AC);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #F8FFAE, #43C6AC);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;

}

.vh-90 {
    max-height: 90vh;
    z-index: 44444 !important;
    height: 90vh;
}

.vh-50 {
    max-height: 50vh;
    /* z-index: 44444 !important; */
    height: 50vh;
}

.vh-84 {
    max-height: 84vh;
    /* z-index: 44444 !important; */
    height: 84vh;
}

.bg-transparent {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.388);
    backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.729);
}

.navbg {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);

}

.sidebg {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.279);
}

.sidebg a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.Sidelink,
.IconLink {
    height: 80px;
}

.IconLink {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000;
}

.boxes {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.422);
    position: absolute;
    /* z-index: -10; */
}

.posRel {
    position: relative;
}

.box-top-right {
    right: 30px;
    top: -10px;
}

.box-bottom-left {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30px;
    /* left: -50px; */
}


.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 50%; */
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.238); */
    /* background: red; */
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.sidebar a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 160px;
    /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
.hideSidebar{
    width: 0px;
    transition: .3s;
    /* width: 20%; */
}
.btn-transparent{
    /* border: 1px solid ; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-transparent:active{
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
.overflowC{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.overflowH{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container bg-transparent vh-90 my-3 rounded  overflowC">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 navbg posRel d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" width="70" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <button id="mySidebtn" class=" btn-transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-2 sidebg d-flex justify-content-center vh-84 w0" style="transition: .3s;">
                <!-- <div class="d-flex mt-3 flex-column  vh-50 text-white">
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="sidebar w0" style="transition: .3s;">
                    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Services</a>
                    <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Clients</a>
                    <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h2>Content Comes Here </h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                     Aliquam, consequatur expedita. Nemo impedit harum veritatis ipsum ullam nihil nobis iure
                      doloremque eius animi ducimus, soluta necessitatibus, vitae a nisi eligendi dolore assumenda 
                      beatae voluptates, incidunt maxime sint. Iure quis aspernatur, atque laborum sit ea corrupti, r
                      epudiandae
                       rem
                        hic blanditiis ab! Corporis, sequi itaque, sapiente minima cum autem, facere
                         quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eos quos mollitia voluptatibus quas sit, quo tenetur illo facilis sequi iure, vitae ea repellat distinctio corrupti maiores blanditiis sint repudiandae, ipsum itaque quidem. Deserunt blanditiis reiciendis consequatur vitae aliquam quam labore praesentium odit eum velit nulla, doloremque accusantium optio consectetur molestiae dolorem sit provident dolores necessitatibus totam minima pariatur voluptatibus! Distinctio, vitae eaque fuga similique, voluptatibus eveniet dolorum molestias sunt cum ipsum veniam a odio recusandae ex culpa! Fugiat voluptates commodi voluptate nulla illum necessitatibus reiciendis, minus nobis unde amet perferendis nostrum optio repellat, fuga aliquid tempora explicabo dignissimos. Dolorum facere vero dolore necessitatibus earum nemo commodi, qui, eveniet dolor a odio illo voluptatem ad, aspernatur itaque doloremque atque? Delectus corporis dolorem nobis rem ipsum! Impedit dicta dolor ex ratione omnis facere tempore pariatur et aperiam voluptas sapiente odit, itaque minima eos vel nihil? Iusto natus quaerat enim hic neque dicta iste voluptatem placeat mollitia sint rem, est fugiat asperiores blanditiis eos iure nemo necessitatibus qui? Unde nihil deleniti eos veritatis ipsam dicta optio tenetur labore! Quibusdam esse veniam fuga neque eum dolores, nulla vero eaque dignissimos dicta expedita mollitia! Harum autem obcaecati explicabo fugiat ipsum reiciendis praesentium ipsam molestiae tempore earum! Adipisci maxime expedita earum! Sed accusamus unde cupiditate doloribus. Facere molestias ducimus natus veniam, aliquam quae quos consectetur beatae eos perspiciatis reprehenderit nemo magnam ipsa doloremque id illo fugit nobis dignissimos dicta officiis et. Autem impedit itaque reprehenderit, obcaecati quibusdam illum aspernatur cupiditate? Iste sint minus cupiditate facere natus exercitationem, ducimus rem, praesentium at, eaque accusamus suscipit fugiat veniam commodi rerum quibusdam dolore. Praesentium, commodi. Quis quos nihil deserunt fuga optio cum provident perferendis. Laboriosam, asperiores architecto. Inventore exercitationem cupiditate laudantium, natus nulla at illum hic commodi beatae, magni velit minima ratione esse, officiis illo eos sint alias!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-top-right boxes"></div>
    <div class="box-bottom-left boxes"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Summary:**
So I want to make a fixed sidebar when someone scrolls my content then the side bar should be fixed at that time and that's it

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `height` from the sidebar and from its parent. To make it fixed, you can use `position: sticky`.

Check out the snippet below with your updated code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mySidebtn').click(()=>{
        $('.sidebg').toggleClass('hideSidebar')
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('hideSidebar')
    })
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    background: #43C6AC;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F8FFAE, #43C6AC);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #F8FFAE, #43C6AC);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;

}

.vh-90 {
    max-height: 90vh;
    z-index: 44444 !important;
    height: 90vh;
}

.vh-50 {
    max-height: 50vh;
    /* z-index: 44444 !important; */
    height: 50vh;
}

.vh-84 {
    max-height: 84vh;
    /* z-index: 44444 !important; */
    height: 84vh;
}

.bg-transparent {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.388);
    backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.729);
}

.navbg {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);

}

.sidebg {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.279);
}

.sidebg a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.Sidelink,
.IconLink {
    height: 80px;
}

.IconLink {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000;
}

.boxes {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.422);
    position: absolute;
    /* z-index: -10; */
}

.posRel {
    position: relative;
}

.box-top-right {
    right: 30px;
    top: -10px;
}

.box-bottom-left {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30px;
    /* left: -50px; */
}


.sidebar {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 50%; */
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.238); */
    /* background: red; */
    z-index: 1;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.sidebar a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 160px;
    /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
.hideSidebar{
    width: 0px;
    transition: .3s;
    /* width: 20%; */
}
.btn-transparent{
    /* border: 1px solid ; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-transparent:active{
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
.overflowC{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.overflowH{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container bg-transparent vh-90 my-3 rounded  overflowC">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 navbg posRel d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" width="70" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <button id="mySidebtn" class=" btn-transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-2 sidebg justify-content-center w0" style="transition: .3s;">
                <!-- <div class="d-flex mt-3 flex-column  vh-50 text-white">
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="IconLink">
                        <a href="#" id="about" class="Sidelink">About</a>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="sidebar w0" style="transition: .3s;">
                    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Services</a>
                    <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Clients</a>
                    <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h2>Content Comes Here </h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                     Aliquam, consequatur expedita. Nemo impedit harum veritatis ipsum ullam nihil nobis iure
                      doloremque eius animi ducimus, soluta necessitatibus, vitae a nisi eligendi dolore assumenda 
                      beatae voluptates, incidunt maxime sint. Iure quis aspernatur, atque laborum sit ea corrupti, r
                      epudiandae
                       rem
                        hic blanditiis ab! Corporis, sequi itaque, sapiente minima cum autem, facere
quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?
quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?
quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?
quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?

                         quaerat minus illum labore tempora sunt mollitia vel. Ex tenetur quia et sapiente ullam, ducimus, reprehenderit impedit, explicabo eaque officia consectetur? Nisi pariatur cum quisquam voluptatem cumque, laborum sint vitae blanditiis obcaecati, quasi error. Consectetur repudiandae id nisi voluptates rem nesciunt nemo voluptate est odit error corrupti ex quasi illo, aspernatur, aperiam sapiente fugit quisquam facilis? Harum vitae quis consequatur reiciendis saepe rerum aliquid distinctio sint ratione expedita ad eum, libero et, debitis quasi inventore magnam itaque iure dolore eius consequuntur repudiandae. Quod quidem voluptatem eveniet, velit repudiandae aliquam eos harum voluptates, nemo deleniti nesciunt voluptatum rerum aliquid vero ex ad, unde dolorum ratione quo! Dignissimos illo corrupti rerum. Repellat magni deserunt, culpa, illo fugit necessitatibus dolore consectetur non eum impedit sapiente modi quam doloremque, quisquam ad atque neque voluptates iste fuga veniam praesentium? Ut amet dolor quas nam laborum commodi sapiente?
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eos quos mollitia voluptatibus quas sit, quo tenetur illo facilis sequi iure, vitae ea repellat distinctio corrupti maiores blanditiis sint repudiandae, ipsum itaque quidem. Deserunt blanditiis reiciendis consequatur vitae aliquam quam labore praesentium odit eum velit nulla, doloremque accusantium optio consectetur molestiae dolorem sit provident dolores necessitatibus totam minima pariatur voluptatibus! Distinctio, vitae eaque fuga similique, voluptatibus eveniet dolorum molestias sunt cum ipsum veniam a odio recusandae ex culpa! Fugiat voluptates commodi voluptate nulla illum necessitatibus reiciendis, minus nobis unde amet perferendis nostrum optio repellat, fuga aliquid tempora explicabo dignissimos. Dolorum facere vero dolore necessitatibus earum nemo commodi, qui, eveniet dolor a odio illo voluptatem ad, aspernatur itaque doloremque atque? Delectus corporis dolorem nobis rem ipsum! Impedit dicta dolor ex ratione omnis facere tempore pariatur et aperiam voluptas sapiente odit, itaque minima eos vel nihil? Iusto natus quaerat enim hic neque dicta iste voluptatem placeat mollitia sint rem, est fugiat asperiores blanditiis eos iure nemo necessitatibus qui? Unde nihil deleniti eos veritatis ipsam dicta optio tenetur labore! Quibusdam esse veniam fuga neque eum dolores, nulla vero eaque dignissimos dicta expedita mollitia! Harum autem obcaecati explicabo fugiat ipsum reiciendis praesentium ipsam molestiae tempore earum! Adipisci maxime expedita earum! Sed accusamus unde cupiditate doloribus. Facere molestias ducimus natus veniam, aliquam quae quos consectetur beatae eos perspiciatis reprehenderit nemo magnam ipsa doloremque id illo fugit nobis dignissimos dicta officiis et. Autem impedit itaque reprehenderit, obcaecati quibusdam illum aspernatur cupiditate? Iste sint minus cupiditate facere natus exercitationem, ducimus rem, praesentium at, eaque accusamus suscipit fugiat veniam commodi rerum quibusdam dolore. Praesentium, commodi. Quis quos nihil deserunt fuga optio cum provident perferendis. Laboriosam, asperiores architecto. Inventore exercitationem cupiditate laudantium, natus nulla at illum hic commodi beatae, magni velit minima ratione esse, officiis illo eos sint alias!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-top-right boxes"></div>
    <div class="box-bottom-left boxes"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```